# batch for loop string shortening

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, filenames

fnAlright. I have files that get exported but saved as *.bin files. each has their respective ending in the actual name.

Therefor I export png files as filename_png.bin.
But how do I do this in a for loop?

```
@echo off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%F in (*.bin) do (
    set fn=%%~nF
    set file=!fn:~0,-3!.!fn:~-2,-0!
    ren %%F %%~dpF%file%
)
```

This doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @SureshKoya - This is Windows

Comment: Do you have powershell?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working.

```
@echo off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%F in (*.bin) do (
    set fn=%%~nF
    set file=!fn:~0,-4!.!fn:~-3,3!
    echo !file!
    ren %%F "%%~dpF!file!"
)
pause>nul
```

But is there a way to get these %%F files into the string manipulation thing directly?